# Styling bootstrap multi-select dropdowns

Tags: select, twitter-bootstrap-3

Does anyone have any good advice for implementing cross-browser styling for multi select Dropdowns within a reasonable sized Boostrap form?

I have read up about - http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/ and it looks perfect but it doesnt mention browser or device support anywhere - which is my main concern.

Answer (score 1):

You can always take advantage of Bootstrap dropdowns and have an `<input type="hidden">` within the `li`. I had a project recently where I had to attach many functions based on a multi-select dropdown, there was really no fluid solution without adding third party solutions, so I built my own. It's pretty lean and works cross browser. Maybe this might be able to help you:

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/panoply/fsvr43ew/3/

You will need to configure it to best suit you and your project. If you like it or it helps you remember to +1. Goodluck.